# unable to get the previous value in the input on cancel click using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here i am creating a crud operation where all the functionalities are working except 1 issue when user click on **edit** and then 2 button's will be enabled **save & cancel** and user types some thing but he choses to **cancel** but then also we are getting the modified input of old input

**ex in input u have 45 value user clicked on edit --> instead of 45 he entered 4 and he pressed cancel even though he has to get 45 in put but instead we are getting 4 after pressing cancel below is my code** n stackvblitz

```
 <tbody>
                   {this.state.employeeResponse.map((response,index) => {
                       return (

                           <tr key={index}>
                                <td >{index + 1}</td>
                                <td >{response.id}</td>
                                <td >{response.employee_name}</td>
                                <td > { index !== this.state.isEditable ?<span>{response.employee_salary}</span>: <input type="text" ref={this.empSalary}  value={response.employee_salary} id="empSalary" onChange={(event)=>{
                              let data = this.state.employeeResponse;
                              data[index].employee_salary = event.target.value
                              this.setState({employeeResponse: data})
}} />}</td>                             
                                <td > {index !== this.state.isEditable?<span>{response.employee_deportment}</span>:<input type="text" ref={this.empDeportment} value={response.employee_deportment}  id="empDeportment" onChange={(event)=>{
                              let data = this.state.employeeResponse;
                              data[index].employee_deportment = event.target.value
                              this.setState({employeeResponse: data})
}} />}</td>
                                <td>
                                    {
                                      index !== this.state.isEditable ? <button  className="button-group action-button edit-button-group" onClick={()=> this.editEmployee(index)} >Edit</button>:<button  className="button-group action-button save-button-group" onClick={()=>this.saveEmployeeDetails(index)} >Save</button>
                                    }
                                    {
                                      index !== this.state.isEditable ? <button  className="button-group action-button delete-button" onClick={()=> this.deleteEmployee(response.id)} >Delete</button>:<button  className="button-group action-button cancel-button-group" onClick={this.cancelEmployeeDetails}>Cancel</button>
                                    }

                                </td>
                           </tr>                          

                       )
                   })}
                   </tbody>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-we1aze

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are saving state in your onChange event. One way to do this instead is to:

1. Remove the onChange event for the inputs
2. Load state into the new inputs when you click the "Edit" button
3. Save state when they click the "Save" button
4. Ignore input when they click the Cancel button.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change your array data directly, while the user is typing, change it when the user clicks save. Add two new variables in state for salary and department.

```
state = {
  employeeResponse: [...]
  isEditable: null,
  employee_deportment: '',
  employee_salary: '',
}
```

When the user clicks save get the values from state, and update your data.

```
saveEmployeeDetails = (index) => {

  const empResp = this.state.employeeResponse;
  empResp[index].employee_salary = this.state.employee_salary;
  empResp[index].employee_deportment = this.state.employee_deportment;
  ...
}
```

Change your inputs to be

```
<input .... id="empSalary" onChange={(event) => this.setState({ employee_salary: event.target.value })} />
<inoput ... id="empDeportment" onChange={(event) => this.setState({ employee_deportment: event.target.value })} />
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class EmployeeDetails extends React.Component {

  state = {
    employeeResponse: [
      {
        "id": "151",
        "employee_name": "john",
        "employee_salary": "57000",
        "employee_age": "29",
        "employee_deportment": "admin",

      },

      {
        "id": "152",
        "employee_name": "mX",
        "employee_salary": "5000",
        "employee_age": "28",
        "employee_deportment": "admin",

      },
      {
        "id": "153",
        "employee_name": "X",
        "employee_salary": "500",
        "employee_age": "29",
        "employee_deportment": "admin",

      }
    ],
    isEditable: null,
    employee_deportment: '',
    employee_salary: '',
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    // Create the ref
    this.empSalary = React.createRef();
    this.empDeportment = React.createRef();
  }

  loadEmployees = () => {
    let url = 'http://localhost:3000/employee-details';
    fetch(url)
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ employeeResponse: data })

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

  reLoadEmployees = () => {
    this.setState.employeeResponse = {};
    this.loadEmployees();
  }
  appendEmployees = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {

      const maxId = Math.max(...prevState.employeeResponse.map(e => parseInt(e.id)));

      const newEmployees = prevState.employeeResponse.slice(0, 10).map((e, i) => ({
        ...e,
        id: (maxId + i + 1)
      }));

      return {
        employeeResponse: [...prevState.employeeResponse, ...newEmployees]
      }
    });

    console.log(this.state.employeeResponse);
    let url = "http://localhost:4000/append-employee";
    fetch(url, { method: 'POST', headers: new Headers(), body: JSON.stringify(this.state.employeeResponse) })
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })




  }
  deleteAllEmployees = () => {
    this.setState({ employeeResponse: [] });


  }
  editEmployee = (index) => {

    const current = this.state.employeeResponse[index];

    this.setState({ isEditable: index, employee_salary: current.employee_salary, employee_deportment: current.employee_deportment });
  }

  saveEmployeeDetails = (index) => {

    const empResp = this.state.employeeResponse;
    empResp[index].employee_salary = this.state.employee_salary;
    empResp[index].employee_deportment = this.state.employee_deportment;
    this.setState({ isEditable: -1 });
    const employeeDetails = {
      'id': empResp[index].id,
      'employee_name': empResp[index].employee_name,
      'employee_salary': this.empSalary.current.value,
      'employee_deportment': this.empDeportment.current.value
    };


    let url = "http://localhost:4000/update-employee";
    fetch(url, { method: 'POST', headers: new Headers(), body: JSON.stringify(employeeDetails) })
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({ employeeResponse: data })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })




  }

  deleteEmployee = (id) => {
    const data = this.state.employeeResponse.filter(i => i.id !== id)
    this.setState({ employeeResponse: data });
  }
  cancelEmployeeDetails = () => {
    this.setState({ isEditable: -1 });
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Employee Details</h2>
        <div className="button-nav flex-start">
          <button className="button-list button-group secondary-button" id="load-employee" onClick={this.loadEmployees}>Load</button>
          <button className="button-list button-group secondary-button" id="reload-employee" onClick={this.reLoadEmployees}>Reload</button>
          <button className="button-list button-group secondary-button" id="append-employee" onClick={this.appendEmployees}>Append</button>
          <button className="button-list button-group secondary-button" id="delete-all-employee" onClick={this.deleteAllEmployees}>Delete All</button>
        </div>

        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>S.No</th>
              <th>Employee ID</th>
              <th>Employee Name</th>
              <th>Employee Salary (K)</th>
              <th>Department</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.employeeResponse.map((response, index) => {
              return (

                <tr key={index}>
                  <td >{index + 1}</td>
                  <td >{response.id}</td>
                  <td >{response.employee_name}</td>
                  <td > {index !== this.state.isEditable ? <span>{response.employee_salary}</span> : <input type="text" ref={this.empSalary} value={this.state.employee_salary} id="empSalary" onChange={(event) => this.setState({ employee_salary: event.target.value })} />}</td>
                  <td > {index !== this.state.isEditable ? <span>{response.employee_deportment}</span> : <input type="text" ref={this.empDeportment} value={this.state.employee_deportment} id="empDeportment" onChange={(event) => this.setState({ employee_deportment: event.target.value })} />}</td>
                  <td>
                    {
                      index !== this.state.isEditable ? <button className="button-group action-button edit-button-group" onClick={() => this.editEmployee(index)} >Edit</button> : <button className="button-group action-button save-button-group" onClick={() => this.saveEmployeeDetails(index)} >Save</button>
                    }
                    {
                      index !== this.state.isEditable ? <button className="button-group action-button delete-button" onClick={() => this.deleteEmployee(response.id)} >Delete</button> : <button className="button-group action-button cancel-button-group" onClick={this.cancelEmployeeDetails}>Cancel</button>
                    }

                  </td>
                </tr>

              )
            })}
          </tbody>

        </table>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<EmployeeDetails />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```